# Declare less variable based on body ID

Tags: css, less

I would like to have a different color for a variable based on the body id

```
<body id="theme1">

#theme1{
    @brand-color:red;
}
#theme2{
    @brand-color:green;
}

h1{color:@brand-color}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `#theme1`? Hashtags denote IDs. Dots denote classes.

Comment: The theme1 changes depending on what part of the site the user is on i.e products may use theme2

Comment: Then can't you just use `body`? It depends how you want to break up your colours. If you want a different colour for both themes, you'll need to use both `#theme1` and `#theme2`.

Comment: Less variables do not work this way. Note the Less is compiled to CSS knowing nothing of your HTML so when this happens Less compiler has no idea of what your `body` id is so it simply can't any `@brand-color` value.

Comment: Well, there're many different methods to achieve what you want, start with reading "Related"-at-the-left Q/As here and search using keywords like "theming" and so on to find some common solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use **[Less variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature)** as CSS **properties**, but rather as **values**. What you need to do is define two different variables that are associated to the two colours you want, and then call the relevant variable based on the theme ID:

```
<body id="theme1">
<body id="theme2">

@brand-color-1: red;
@brand-color-2: green;

#theme1 {
  color: @brand-color-1;
}
#theme2 {
  color: @brand-color-2;
}
```

This will compile to the following (with `<div>` in place of `<body>`):

```css
#theme1 {
  color: red;
}
#theme2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="theme1">
  Theme 1
</div>
<div id="theme2">
  Theme 2
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sorry, ive tried this and it does not work as you cannot declare a variable twice? i.e @brand-color

Comment: @ScottPedder -- I've updated my answer to cover this :)

Answer (score -1):

While you are dealing with `id` you have to use `#` sign for css

`.` sign is used for class selectors

Modify your code like this

```
<body id="theme1">

#theme1{
    @brand-color:red;
}
#theme2{
    @brand-color:green;
}
h1{
    color:@brand-color
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo

Comment: Is it so that you want or do you want something else?